# Error compiling CMake project with Emscripten

Tags: c, cmake, ubuntu-16.04, emscripten

I have written a project that compiles with CMake. Now I am trying to get emscripten to compile it, but I am getting an error. Beginning in the root of the Cmake project, the steps I take are as follows:

```
$mkdir build_emscripten
$cd build_emscripten

$emcmake cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo
$sudo make
```

Everything works up until the command make. What happens is it links the C executable successfully then it gives the error `"ERROR:root:/usr/include/python2.7: Input file has an unknown suffix, don't know what to do with it!"`

Then it proceeds to give multiple other errors causes by this. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Which version of emscripten are you using ?
Here, emscripten seems to be trying to compile the python executable as a source file, which obviously isn't going to be successful. To be more precise, the error comes from here : https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/6dc4ac5f9e4d8484e273e4dcc554f809738cedd6/emcc.py#L890
You could try to run make in verbose mode to display the generated faulty command.

Comment: And you usually do not have to run `make` with `sudo` System-wide `make install` does require it (meanwhile, it is better to use it with something like `checkinstall`), but for projects built with Emscripten you unlikely to need to install it system-wide.